# How to identify incomplete details for each id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**I have the following data frame:**

```
emp_id  male    female   Month_Year
423       0       0      March-2016
423       0       0      April-2016 
423       0       1      May-2016
423       0       1      June-2016

789       1       0      June-2017
789       1       0      July-2017
789       1       0      August-2017
789       0       0      September-2017

856       1       0      March-2018
856       1       0      April-2018

987       0       1      June-2019
987       0       1      July-2019
987       0       1      August-2019
```

Please note in the columns `male` and `female` the values indicate as mentioned below:

```
1 - "Yes"
0 - "No"
```

I need something like this,

**Expected data frame:**

[image]

Please note in the `Var` column, the values indicate as follows:

```
1 - "the gender details are not missing"
0 - "the gender details are missing"
```

**Also, take note that one emp_id can be either male or female and not both.**

If observed in the columns `male` and `female`,

For `emp_id 423`, there are no gender details present for the first two rows. So I am giving value as zero in the Var column.

For `emp_id 789`, the gender detail is missing for the last row. So I have mentioned zero in the Var column.

For `emp_id 856 and 987`, gender details are not missing over a particular period. So I am giving value as one in the Var column.

**I used the below code:**

```
mask = (df.assign(zeros=df['male'].eq(0))
          .groupby('emp_id')[['male', 'zeros']]
          .transform('sum')
          .all(axis=1))
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)

mask = (df.assign(zeros=df['female'].eq(0))
          .groupby('emp_id')[['female', 'zeros']]
          .transform('sum')
          .all(axis=1))
df2 = df[mask]
print (df2)
```

**Output from the above code:**

[image]

[image]

By using the above code, I was able to capture the emp_id which is having missing details in male and female columns separately.

Is there any other way that I can compare both columns(male and female) at a time and represent the missing details in the Var column.

So please let me know the solution:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['var']  =  (df.male + df.female).groupby(df.emp_id).transform('min')

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
    emp_id  male  female      Month_Year  var
0      423     0       0      March-2016    0
1      423     0       0      April-2016    0
2      423     0       1        May-2016    0
3      423     0       1       June-2016    0
4      789     1       0       June-2017    0
5      789     1       0       July-2017    0
6      789     1       0     August-2017    0
7      789     0       0  September-2017    0
8      856     1       0      March-2018    1
9      856     1       0      April-2018    1
10     987     0       1       June-2019    1
11     987     0       1       July-2019    1
12     987     0       1     August-2019    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ShashidharR: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)